# How can I let an animated .svg element resize with window size, but stay in its position on the screen?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, animation, svg

I'm trying to create an animation with CSS.
It consists of several .svg's.

There are two challenges I can't seem to find a solution for:

1. How can I make it that the 'rails' element extends with the width of the browser, while staying in place? When using width:100% or width:100vw; the element starts moving when I make the browser window. Making it look weird (the train should stay on the rails ;-) )
2. How can I let the css animation work on mobile Safari? It seems to work on iOS/iPadOS 15.1, but not on previous versions.

```css
.rails img {
position:absolute;
width:1300px;
right:0;
top:238px;
}
.trein-animatie {
height:300px;
width:auto;
background-image: url("https://groenhuysen.ecdjdemo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Landschap_volgpagina.svg");
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
}

.bord {
position:absolute;
width:175px;
height:auto;
left:10%;
top:51px;
}
.wagon {
width:250px;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
top:155px;
}
.locomotief {
width:270px;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
left:250px;
top:47px;
}

.trein {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:7%;
 -webkit-animation: linear;
 -webkit-animation-name: binnenrijden;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation:linear;
    animation-name:binnenrijden;
    animation-duration:3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes binnenrijden {
  0% {
    left:-600px;
  }
  100% {
    left:7%;    
  }
}
@keyframes binnenrijden {
  0% {
    left:-600px;
  }
  100% {
    left:7%;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trein-animatie">
<div class="bord"><img src="https://groenhuysen.ecdjdemo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Modulebord_1.svg"></div>
<div class="trein"><div class="wagon"><img src="https://groenhuysen.ecdjdemo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Wagon_module_1_De_opgeruimde_werkplek.svg"></div><div class="locomotief"><img src="https://groenhuysen.ecdjdemo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Locomotief_witte_rand.svg"></div></div><div class="rails"><img src="https://groenhuysen.ecdjdemo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Logo_roze_groen.png"></div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well the second question i don't know , im not an apple user. First question answer: if you want the "rails" element to extend with the width of the browser and 100% isn't working i think u could just put the size of the width of the screen like for example 1080px. Or a very complicated way would be to make the page read the width of your screen and then the width to be equal with the variable of your screen width size.

Comment: Or at the second question you could use .gif